# Cascading three ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, cascading

My Windows form has three comboboxes. CmdCountry references a child table of CmdContinent, and CmdCity references a child table of CmdCountry.

But I get error like "wrong format" When I try to get ContinentId from cmbContinent_SelectedIndexChanged by coding.

```
int ContId = Convert.Into32(cmbContinent.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

My first two Comboboxes are like following:

```
private void Continent()
{
    var continent = (from u in db.Continent
                     select new { u.ContinentName,  u.ContinentId }
                    ).ToList();
    cmbContinent.DataSource = continent;
    cmbContinent.DisplayMember = "ContinentName";
    cmbContinent.ValueMember = "ContinentId";
}

private void cmbContinent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbContinent.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
    { 
        int ContId = Convert.Into32(cmbContinent.SelectedValue.ToString()); // Here I get the error
        var country = (from u in db.Country
                       where u.ContinentId == ContId
                       select new { u.CountryId, u.CountryName }).ToList();

        cmbCountry.DataSource = country;
        cmbCountry.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
        cmbCountry.ValueMember = "CountryId";
    }
}
```

And loading first combobox Continent in Constructor:

```
public NewAccount()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    Continent();
}
```

I would be appreciated if anybody could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a ComboBox in my current project and I do something similar.

```
int valueMax = Convert.ToInt32(cbxNumberValues.SelectedItem);
```

For your code here is something that should work. Note that I've done little modification to be more conventionally coded.

```
int contId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbContinent.SelectedItem);
```

I would also suggest to use 'cbx' or 'cmb' and not 'cmd' as it tend to usually say command. But that's not very important

Comment: I think the `cmd` is a typo in the question, as the code does use `cmb`. And personally I am (well, was) a `cbo` guy :)

Comment: @Toucanite Thank you for your responce, I don't know why but now it's working as I did from the begining  int continentId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbContinent.SelectedValue.ToString());

Comment: @HelenTekie If the typo in your original post were in the code it might explain it.

Comment: @Toucanite  sorry, now I get the same problem to my 3rd combobox. Very strange ...I get the same error

Comment: @HelenTekie Glad to hear it, hope I was of any help. Good luck for your project.